# SQL integer division returns 0 rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a calculated field called efficiency %. This is calculated by taking LaborDtl.LaborHrs minus Calculated_Shouldhavetaken divided by Calculated_Shouldhavetaken. When I run the query I get zero rows returned, but creating the calculated field without the division returns the difference as expected. I believe this is due to how division is treated in the server.

```
/*
 * Disclaimer!!!
 * This is not a real query being executed, but a simplified version for general vision.
 * Executing it with any other tool may produce a different result.
 */
 
select 
    [LaborDtl].[JobNum] as [LaborDtl_JobNum],
    [JobHead].[PartNum] as [JobHead_PartNum],
    [LaborDtl].[EmployeeNum] as [LaborDtl_EmployeeNum],
    [LaborDtl].[OpCode] as [LaborDtl_OpCode],
    [JobHead].[ProdQty] as [JobHead_ProdQty],
    (LaborDtl.LaborQty + LaborDtl.ScrapQty) as [Calculated_TotalQty],
    [LaborDtl].[LaborHrs] as [LaborDtl_LaborHrs],
    (TotalQty/ JobHead.ProdQty* LaborDtl.LaborHrs* 1.0) as [Calculated_Shouldhavetaken],
    [LaborDtl].[ClockInDate] as [LaborDtl_ClockInDate],
    ((LaborDtl.LaborHrs- Shouldhavetaken)/ Shouldhavetaken) as [Calculated_effpercent]
from Erp.LaborDtl as LaborDtl
inner join Erp.JobOper as JobOper on 
    LaborDtl.Company = JobOper.Company
    and LaborDtl.JobNum = JobOper.JobNum
    and LaborDtl.AssemblySeq = JobOper.AssemblySeq
    and LaborDtl.OprSeq = JobOper.OprSeq
inner join Erp.JobOpDtl as JobOpDtl on 
    JobOper.Company = JobOpDtl.Company
    and JobOper.JobNum = JobOpDtl.JobNum
    and JobOper.AssemblySeq = JobOpDtl.AssemblySeq
    and JobOper.OprSeq = JobOpDtl.OprSeq
inner join Erp.JobHead as JobHead on 
    JobOpDtl.Company = JobHead.Company
    and JobOpDtl.JobNum = JobHead.JobNum
where (LaborDtl.ClockInDate = dateadd (day, -1, Constants.Today))
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Selecting `JobHead.ProdQty, LaborDtl.LaborHrs, Shouldhavetaken` should show that in one of the rows, at least one of these fields contain a `0`.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Calculations in your `SELECT` have no influence on the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

It could be as you mentioned.  Any chance you could encapsulate the query and do your calculation for the division part outside just to test it?

Try casting decimal around Shouldhavetaken

```
CAST(Shouldhavetaken AS DECIMAL(9,2))
```

or something like that.  See if works.

Another test you can run is to hardcode an int as the divisor and hardcode a decimal and see if you get different results.   / 2 or / 2.0